# Unable to send underscore with Sendkeys in C#?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I've been bored, so I tried to make a program that writes a Look of Disapproval smiley(the ಠ_ಠ face) when pressing ctrl+shift+L.
Now everything works, except for the underscore that is in the smiley, which won't get written at all.

This was what I used first:

```
SendKeys.Send("ಠ_ಠ");
```

I've tried various things, like adding {} brackets around the underscore, and of course I googled this too.

Is there any way I can get the underscore to get sent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for programming out of boredom. Good cause.

Comment: It's got to be some character encoding thing. `ಠ` is not ASCII.

Comment: The ಠ's are sent just fine, it's the _ that is broken for some reason :\

Comment: Actually, it seems that not anything is being written that I put inbetween the eyes. Well there's one clue.

Comment: What keyboard layout do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Mixing different encodings creates weird result. [ಠ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0ca0/index.htm) is Unicode, `_` is ASCII. Different length characters confuse and iritate Visual Studio.

Try:

```
SendKeys.Send("\u0CA0_\u0CA0");
```

Or:

```
SendKeys.Send("\u0CA0\u005F\u0CA0");
```

Comment: That means even though you can type "ಠ_ಠ", that's not interpreted as "ಠ_ಠ", because Visual Studio sees: Unicode, then expects more Unicode and finds something which isn't. The end result makes you *feel* just like your input: ಠ_ಠ.

Comment: Wrong.  Any decent encoding system will handle that fine.

Comment: @SLaks I never said Unicode was decent. :) But seriously, it's a limitation on interpretation of Unicode by VS. Would you agree?

Comment: @SLaks I would find find it very surprising that would give the OP a different result. I actually get `ಠ_ಠ` fine from using "ಠ_ಠ", but only because I'm on some funky un-English keyboard (VS and Windows are in English though).

Comment: The keyboard layout has nothing to do with file encodings.  UTF8 is a robust encoding that can handle any valid sequence of characters.  **This will work on a source level**.  I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: I tried this, and it still didn't write the underscore. And testing it with the messagebox in fact _did_ write it.

Comment: `var form = new Form();
form.Click += delegate { SendKeys.Send("ಠ_ಠ"); };
form.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
Application.Run(form);`

Comment: @JeremyG What are you sending your characters *to* when doing ctrl+shift+l?

Comment: Weird, maybe it's just a problem on my part, in which case some computers would be able to do this and some aren't.

Comment: @MPelletier You mean, as that I'm sending it into notepad?

Comment: @JeremyG So maybe your problem is with notepad. I tried a project where I just send it to the textbox in a form (on Enter). Can you try that?

Comment: @MPelletier: I don't get it. AFAIK either the source file is unicode or it isn't, so how can the underscore be ASCII?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use an english keyboard layout that has the underscore as key you can't just type the ASCII character but have to write it as a combination of modifier and character keys.