# How to send special characters using SendKeys.Send()?

Tags: c#, special-characters, sendkeys, custom-keyboard

I'm developing a touch keyboard for an application (Windows keyboard do not have what I need) using SendKeys.Send() to send the keys when the user presses the buttons. I can send normal keys, like *A, B, C, Backspace, Enter*, and so on. However I was not able to send special chars,  like *á, é, ô, ä, ñ*.

So, is there a way to send these special characters through SendKeys.Send()? If not, what could you suggest me?

Comment: *"I was not able to send special chars"* - how exactly do you send them, to where and what "not able" means?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to send underscore with Sendkeys in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217373/unable-to-send-underscore-with-sendkeys-in-c)

Comment: The `SendKeys` class sends, not surprisingly, _keys_ to the other application, not characters. From the documentation: _"If your application is intended for international use with a variety of keyboards, the use of Send could yield unpredictable results and should be avoided." It is not at all clear what you've tried, since your question offers no code at all, never mind a good [mcve]. But it sounds like you simply misunderstand what `SendKeys` does. If you want characters not directly on the keyboard, you need to send the keys that would form those characters on input.

Answer (score 0):

With this Project, you should be able to send your characters :

http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

```
InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry()
```

or this can also help you:
[C# VS 2012 how to send string to other application in russian language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344066/c-sharp-vs-2012-how-to-send-string-to-other-application-in-russian-language)